# 'The good of the people' & 'follow in everything the general will'

Tags: vocabulary

> The first and most important rule of legitimate or popular government, that is to say, of government whose object is the good of the people, is therefore, as I have observed, to follow in everything the general will
>
> Source: [a sample passage for interpretation](http://gmatclub.com/forum/the-first-and-most-important-rule-of-legitimate-or-popular-g-110284.html)

Would you tell me what the following mean?

> The good of the people
>
> follow in everything the general will

In addition, what does *will* mean here?

Comment: I read both of these *good* and *will* as nouns. *The good of the people* would refer to *the benefit for the people*. *The general will* would refer to *public opinions/thoughts/determination* or *people's opinions/thoughts/determination in general*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I concur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"For the good of the people" means "in the best interests of the citizens". It's an important distinction that the line does *not* mean that the government should always make the most *popular* decision. It's saying that the government should always consider what will most benefit the people that they represent or rule.

The second line (follow in everything the general will) *does* suggest that the government should make the popular choice.

As a whole and without further context, the author is suggesting (wrongly, in my opinion) that the best interests of the people are served by always making the most popular choice.

"Will" in this context means that which the people want and desire. So the government should do what the people want.

It is every parent's "will" that their child be healthy. As children, it is our "will" that our parents always treat us fairly.

EDIT: I addressed the quotes you listed, please do not assume that the answers address the essay in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

This is a passage from [a translation of] an essay by the 18th-century philosopher Jean-Jacques Rousseau, and it deals in 18th-century style with Very Large Abstractions.

- ***The good of the people*** means that The People—all members of the society, taken as a whole—enjoy The Good—all good things, such as prosperity, security, liberty, happiness, and so forth, taken (again) as a whole.

  A “legitimate or popular government”, says Rousseau, is one which takes achieving this Good as its primary “object” or purpose.
- ***Follow*** means “be led by”, as opposed to “lead”: such a government must obey the “general will”.
- ***In everything*** means with respect to *all* matters: there are no matters which the government can decide on its own, without consulting the “general will”.
- ***The general will*** is what everybody-taken-together—The People, again—desires, what it requires the government to do. *Will* is the noun form of the verb *to will*, which is not the ordinary modal auxiliary but the active verb meaning “desire, wish”.

Comment: All your explanations are fantabulous and Great. Thank you all so much